# How can I use :~: to determine type equality in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to use `:~:` from [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) to determine type equality at compile time. My expectation is that it behaves along the line of Scala's standard way of determining type equality:

```
case class Equals[A >: B <:B , B]()

Equals[Int, Int]     // compiles fine
Equals[String, Int]  // doesn't compile
```

So I tried

```
foo :: Int :~: Bool
foo = undefined
```

which I would expect to fail since `Int :~: Bool` is inhabitable. But it compiles just fine.

- How is `:~:` supposed to work? The documentation of `Data.Type.Equality` is pretty impenetrable to me and I was not able to find a succinct example anywhere.
- Maybe I'm completely off the track. In that case, how could I achieve the semantics of the `Equals` example in Haskell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Much as we Haskellers often pretend otherwise, every normal<sup>1</sup> type in Haskell is inhabited. That includes `data Void`, and it includes `a :~: b` for all `a` and `b`. Besides the polite values we usually acknowledge, there is also the bottom value.

`undefined :: a` is one way of producing the bottom value in any type `a`. So in particular `undefined :: Int :~: Bool`, and thus your code is perfectly **type** correct.

If you want a type equality that simply fails to compile if the equality can't be proved at compile time, then you want a type equality constraint (which is the `~` operator), not the `:~:` type. You use that like this:

```
foo :: Int ~ Int => ()   -- compiles fine
foo = ()

bar :: Int ~ Bool => ()  -- does technically compile
bar = ()
```

`bar` compiles only because constraints are *assumed* in the body of a function that has the constraints. But any attempt to *call* `bar` requires the compiler is able to prove the constraints in order to compile the *call*. So this fails:

```
baz :: ()
baz = bar
```

`:~:`, however, is not a constraint (it doesn't go left of the `=>` arrow in types), but an ordinary type. `a :~: b` is the type of values that serve as a *runtime* proof that the type `a` is equal to the type `b`. If in fact they are **not** equal, your program won't fail to compile just before you expressed the type `a :~: b`; rather you just won't be able to actually come up with a value of that type (other than bottom).

In particular, `a :~: b` is a type that has a data constructor: `Refl`. To usefully use it, you usually require a `a :~: b` as an argument. and then pattern match on it. Within the scope of the pattern match (i.e. the body of a `case` statement), the compiler will use the assumption that the two types are equal. Since pattern matching on the bottom value will never succeed (it might throw an exception, or it might compute forever), the fact that you can always provide bottom as a "proof" that `a :~: b` doesn't actually cause huge problems; you can lie to the compiler, but it will never execute code that depended on your lie.

Examples corresponding to those in the OP would be:

```
foo :: Int :~: Int -> ()
foo proof
  = case proof of
      Refl  -> ()

bar :: Int :~: Bool -> ()
bar proof
  = case proof of
      Refl  -> ()
```

`bar` can exist even though it *needs* an impossible proof. We can even *call* `bar` with something like `bar undefined`, making use of the bottom value in the type `Int :~: Bool`. This won't be detected as an error at compile time, but it will throw a runtime exception (if it's actually evaluated; lazy evaluation might avoid the error). Whereas `foo` can simply be called with `foo Refl`.

`:~:` (and `~`) is of course much more usefully used when the two types are (or contain) variables, rather than simple concrete types like `Int` and `Bool`. It's also frequently combined with something like `Maybe` so you have a way of expressing when the types are *not* proven to be equal. A slightly less trivial example would be:

```
strange :: Maybe (a :~: b) -> a -> b -> [a]
strange Nothing x _ = [x]
strange (Just Refl) x y
  = [x, y]
```

`strange` takes a maybe-proof that the types `a` and `b` are equal, and a value of each. If the maybe is `Nothing`, then the types might not be equal, so we can only put `x` in the list of `a`. If we get `Just Refl`, however, then `a` and `b` are actually the same type (*inside the pattern match only!*), so it's valid to put `x` and `y` in the same list.

But this does show a feature of `:~:` that cannot be achieved with `~`. We can still call `strange` even when we want to pass it two values of *different* types; we just in that case are forced to pass `Nothing` as the first value (or `Just undefined`, but that won't get us anything useful). It allows us to write code that contemplates that `a` and `b` *could* be equal, without forcing a compilation failure if they actually aren't. Whereas `a ~ b` (in the constraints) would only allow us to require that they definitely are equal, and provably so at compile time.

---

<sup>1</sup> Where "normal type" means a member of the kind `Type` AKA `*`.

Comment: `foo :: Int ~ Bool => (); foo = ()` does compile fine

Comment: @Noughtmare Ah, dammit. Does a call to `foo` at least fail to compile?

Comment: @Noughtmare Yes, it does. I'll fix.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, this is very helpful. Turns out that I didn't understand the part about pattern matching and the `Refl` constructor. In essence, this is very similar to `Equals[String, Int]` in Scala, which tries to force the compiler to "create an instance" of the proof.

Comment: @michid I've done a bit of Scala, but not recently enough to know offhand how your `Equals[String, Int]` compares to `:~:` or `~`. To anyone who reads this and *can* make such a comparison, please feel free to suggest an edit (or write a separate answer).

Comment: man, an explanation like this one is really needed in hackage documentation